# Which episodes do the Overlord movies cover?

Tags: overlord

If I’m correct the Overlord movies are just to recap certain parts of the actual series. Which episodes do the movies cover?

Comment: It's the first season cut together as two movies. There are new scenes, but they don't add anything and are instead distracting sometimes. It's better to just watch the first season instead of these movies.

Answer (score 1):

Both movies together cover basically all 13 episodes of the first season.
Although certain scenes are skipped I don't think that there is a single episode completely missing in the movies.
If I remember correctly episode 10 is the one which is missing the most and is only shown in form of a flashback.

Comment: Oh thank you. Does the second movie cover the second season then or do both movies combined cover the first season?

Comment: @Jackarlston both movies together cover the first season.